# Open txt file inside windows 10 container

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop, windows-container

I have a simple docker container that is based on windows image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903

WORKDIR /app1/

ENTRYPOINT powershell.exe
```

I run it interactively, using:

```
docker run -it -v c:\app1:c:\app1 test-image:1.0
```

There is a file called 1.txt inside app1 folder.

When I run:

```
.\app1\1.txt
```

I see no notepad.exe process, but instead I can spot OpenWith process:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
     78       5     1056       4452       0.02   1940   1 CExecSvc
     74       5     5360       3792       0.02   1904   1 cmd
     81       5      904       1364       0.00   1844   1 CompatTelRunner
    156      10     6532       6088       0.00   1728   1 conhost
     97       7     1196       4980       0.05   1896   1 conhost
    286      13     1836       4976       0.27    984   1 csrss
     37       6     1348       3356       0.06    524   1 fontdrvhost
      0       0       60          8                 0   0 Idle
    831      22     4748      13844       0.17    460   1 lsass
    546      25    13156      28920       0.17   1952   1 OfficeClickToRun
    420      24     7400      28844       0.13   2472   1 OpenWith
    376      22     6732      27168       0.13   2536   1 OpenWith
```

I suspect that some mapping might be missing, event though assoc shows that .txt file is associated with notepad.exe:

```
assoc .txt

.txt=txtfile

ftype txtfile

txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

What might be the problem here? Am I missing some register value?

Answer (score 0):

What good is running notepad.exe in a docker container? It's a GUI program.

It may not be the best solution, but what I do is [install chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install), and then run `choco install nano`, then `nano myfile.txt`.